# Facebook login for Wordpress frontend and Clipshare running under subdomain

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-authentication

I have a website which runs wordpress on www.mysite.com and a clipshare (clip-share.com) installation under video.mysite.com. As you probably know both script support facebook login. Is it possible to authenticate users with fb login for both sites?

Does running clipshare on subdomain have any effect on authorization?